# MapView and AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-mapview, runnable

I am trying to use an AsyncTask class that I created to update a MapView.  The problem is I am getting this error when I make my call to execute the AsyncTask:

```
 "Can't create a Handler inside a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"
```

I have tried running the Task on the UI Thread using

```
Handler hand = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    hand.post(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new RxThread().execute();


        }


    });
```

But that just gives me the same error.  I realize that my MapView doesn't call looper prepare, and that I'm having troubles getting this to work since I'm running the MapView on a seperate activity rather than the Main Activity.  Does anyone have a good solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, your error is because you are first referencing `AsyncTask` on a background thread. You can only create and `execute()` an `AsyncTask` on the main application thread.

Comment: Is there any way around this?

Comment: Just call             new RxThread().execute(); on the main thread.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I'm not calling this in the UI thread, I'm trying to use it in a separate activity.

Comment: @user1345119: "I'm not calling this in the UI thread" -- and that is your problem, as I noted in my answer.